# How to get path of a file in nodejs post request to write some data in the file

Tags: node.js, multer

I am uploading a csv file to server and in the post request of nodejs I want to add one more row at last, csv file already has the headers while uploading.

```
   var multer = require('multer');
   var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
   var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
   var writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false});

   var upload = multer({ 
            storage: storage
            }).single('file');



     exports.uploadContact =(req, res) => {

      upload(req, res, function (err) {

   writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false});

   writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(req.file.fieldname,{flags: 'a'}));

   writer.write({first_name: 'hahahaha'});

   writer.end();
                  });
                      }
```

I tried to add 'hahaha' in the last row below header 'first_name' but it didn't work

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are getting the file (base64 encoded ¿?) from your frontend or another application that is calling your api right? so the file is not yet in your system, therefore there is not path.

Comment: so how can i add one more row in it, actually csv file is coming from frontend, is there a way please?

Comment: I think you should try `req.file.path` instead of providing `req.file.fieldname` to `fs.createWriteStream`. In this callback, Multer has uploaded your file, and augmented the request object with file data. As per Multer's API's file information [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#file-information).